# Replacing my PS4 HDD with an SSD

Tags: ps4, destiny

My PS4 says it's currently using 407GB, since it's supposed to have a 500GB disk, can I assume that the OS is using 93GB?

Can I use a 128GB SSD in the PS4?

Are there any test results (and comparisons) that show SSD performance in Destiny, specifically in the loading screens?

Finally, are there any concrete resources about SSD lifetime in a PS4?

Comment: Firstly, you seem to have answered the question already; *"my 128GB SSD won't do much"*. And secondly, what improvement are you referring to? Load times? Space improvements? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Try to put only one question per question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First of all, let's talk about size.

When it comes to computer, and the PS4 is one too, they calculate space in binary. What this means, is that for your PS4 1 GB is actually 1024 MB. If we were to put a 1 GB drive inside, the PS4 would tell us its size is 0.9 GB, that's because manufacturers advertise their size in decimal instead, so 1 GB would be 1000 MB.

Your PS4 only had 465 GiB (Giga-Binary-Bytes) of space to work with. Since it's leaving you with 408 GiB to store stuff, it's likely the OS takes up around 60 GiB by itself.

A 128 GB SSD will have a size of 119 GiB for your PS4. Minus the 60 GiB for the OS, you'll have about another 60 GiB for your games.

Is 60 GB enough for a PS4?
As of now it probably is, but that would be really borderline. Some game require almost 40 GB for installation, [like *Call of Duty: Ghosts* (39.7 GB) and *Battlefield 4* (34.9 GB)](http://www.videogamer.com/ps4/battlefield_4/news/battlefield_4_ps4_install_size_is_34_9gb.html). Considering a PS4 Bluray can support up to 200 GB and storage requirements aren't likely to go down in the future, I'd say you'll eventually want a larger drive (maybe).

---

#### Is it worth upgrading?

It highly depends on what you consider "worth it". According to several sources online, [including this reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/1qwynm/upgraded_to_ssd_in_my_ps4/), it appears that the PS4 boots significantly faster on an SSD than on an HDD.

> The first thing I have to say is the start up time from standby is improved a lot and is the most significant and noticeable improvement. I can start the system and launch games significantly faster

Games also seem to load faster, though the difference doesn't seem to be as impressive. How much faster also depends on the game. A well optimized game would install itself in a way that would minimize random access, thus offsetting the main advantage SSDs currently have over HDDs.

---

#### What about the PS4's lifetime?

Your PS4's lifetime might improve with an SSD, according to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/39723/215659).

SSDs wear when they are being written on, and modern SSDs can be written on *a lot* (hundreds of GB), *every single day*, *for several years*, before they become unwriteable. It is more likely your HDD will die from a mechanical failure or you'll upgrade to a larger SSD before that happens.

Comment: Not finding much definitive results specific to Destiny, but it seems to be about 10% faster in loading, which isn't significant enough for me. I've also encountered some posts claiming they had issues with a disk smaller than 160gb. Thanks for your informative answer and links. I think I'll just wait and save up for a bigger hdd if I ever need it :)